# How can I save xml data to a file using `XMLNodePrinter`

Tags: xml, groovy

I just started to learn groovy.

My first task is to create a XML Document and save it to a file on disc. Everything works fine until I wan't to store the `document` to disc (I ended up by using a Transformer for output).

Is there a way to store the xml data to file using `XMLNodePrinter`. Here is my code (now it's just creating a blank file):

```
    // CREATING XML FILES WITH GROOVY:
    def builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    def document = builder.newDocument();
    def root = document.createElement("root_node");

    // SIMPLE XML DATA
    for(i in 0..5){
        root.setAttribute("attr" + i, "val" + i);
        def childElement = document.createElement("childNode");
        childElement.setTextContent("" + i);
        root.appendChild(childElement);
    }

    // printing the data to console
    def myXMLFile = "myFirstXML.xml";
    File f  = new File(myXMLFile);
    def writer = new FileWriter(f);     
    new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(writer)).print(root);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `MarkupBuilder`?

```
import groovy.xml.*

new File( 'myFirstXML.xml' ).withWriter { w ->
    def attributes = (0..5).collectEntries { [ "attr$it", "val$it" ] }
    new MarkupBuilder( w ).root_node( attributes ) {
        (0..5).each { i ->
            childNode( "$i" )
        }
    }
}
```

That creates a file `myFirstXML.xml` which contains:

```
<root_node attr0='val0' attr1='val1' attr2='val2' attr3='val3' attr4='val4' attr5='val5'>
  <childNode>0</childNode>
  <childNode>1</childNode>
  <childNode>2</childNode>
  <childNode>3</childNode>
  <childNode>4</childNode>
  <childNode>5</childNode>
</root_node>
```